# How to Add Config map in Azure DevOps for AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, release, azure-aks, configmap

I am trying out few things in AKS. right now I am trying to release to AKS through Azure DevOps. But I am unable to achieve the creation of config map through pipeline. right now, when I run the pipeline all it does is it creates the pods/service mentioned in the deployment.yaml file but unable to create the config map file, but shows the deployment successful.I am using Volume Mounts for the configuration for the application. right now my release file looks like this.

```
steps:
- task: Kubernetes@0
  displayName: 'kubectl apply'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceConnection: 'AKS-Test'
    namespace: testns
    command: apply
    useConfigurationFile: true
    configuration: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DeploymentManifest/deployment.yaml'
    useConfigMapFile: true
    configMapFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DeploymentManifest/configmap.yaml'
```

Manually I used to do like this to test the application. two step process. I don't think I need to add another task just for apply configmap. can someone point me in the right direction.

```
kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

here is the content of configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-config
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Error",
          "System": "Error",
          "Microsoft": "Error"
        }
      },
      "Testing":"ReleaseEnv"
    }
```

**Update:**
For now I have added a new task to apply the configmap and its working not sure this is the right way.

Comment: Hi @codebot, I have tested it on my side and it works, could you please share the full log here? In addition, please also check [this](https://pleasereleaseme.net/a-better-way-of-deploying-a-dockerized-application-to-azure-kubernetes-service-using-azure-pipelines/)

Comment: If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: How can we update the configMap for different environment. Please let me know if you have done it.

Comment: what do you mean by environment ?